# Indentation error for python 2.7

Tags: python

```
def ispermute(str1, str2):
    d1 = {}
    d2 = {}
    for letter in str1:
        if letter not in d1:
            d1[letter] = 1
        else:
            d1[letter] += 1

    for letter in str2:
        if letter not in d2:
            d2[letter] = 1
        else:
            d2[letter] +=1

    if d1 != d2:
        return False
    return True
```

While running this I am getting error as:

```
File "2.py", line 16
    if d1 != d2:
               ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Can someone suggest what is the issue? This code is made to check the permutation of two strings.

Comment: Should work fine - check if you have a mix of tabs and spaces (make it all tabs or all spaces)

Comment: your code is fine. I would suggest to use python IDE to prevent such issue earlier.

Comment: I am running on terminal...and edited on sublime....no idea why its giving issue

Comment: It's not apparent here, but the file you are actually running probably has a mixture of tabs and spaces. Sublime will have a way to make those visible.

Comment: How can it be done..can you suggest something

Comment: Why not just do `collections.Counter(str1) == collections.Counter(str2)`?

Comment: Your return can be simply be `return d1 == d2`

Comment: @StephenRauch: I tried doing return d1 == d2 but still the issue of indentation error

Comment: In pycharm, your code is right. NO Error@Roxy

Comment: @RoadRunner: Thanks..this worked...:)

Comment: @Roxy No problem, just a shorter way to do it. `Counter` basically does all the counting for you. But its always good to understand how to do it manually first, as you've done.

Comment: Source view says it's a tabs and spaces problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed tabs and spaces in your code. If you are usings Sublime Text (as stated in the comments) you can:

1. Select all your text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
2. View -> Indentation -> Convert Indentation to Spaces

You can avoid the problem in the future by turning on "Indent Using Spaces" under the View -> Indentation tab.